# Class method does not invoke on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, methods

I wrote a small class containing 2 class methods for some calculations. I call those methods from another class.
I have declared everything properly in both classes and Xcode does not give any warnings.
Still, I checked with debugger and when I call method from this class it just doesn't invoke

THis is declaration:

```
+(double)DoubleNearestRounding:(double)unrounded
          NumberOfDecimals:(int)decimals;
```

And here is the call from another class:

```
ddd = [DoubleRounding DoubleNearestRounding:[[textField text] doubleValue]
                           NumberOfDecimals:2];
```

Any ideas, what have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know that it isn't working?

Comment: please not only show the declaration, but the function itself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it does work. It seems that debugger didn't want to show steps for unknown reason. Strange, anyway,...

Comment: Were you using step over in the debugger or step in, they do just what they say? Any reason to not just use an NSNumberFormatter to do the work for you?